# No error detected... but if run module don't get output

Tags: python

```py
#generatore di dadi per risultati casuali

class dado:
    materiale = 'plastica'
    
    def __init__ (self, facce = 8):
        self.risultato = 0
        self.facce = facce
        tipi = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20]
        if facce not in tipi:
            print(f'mai sentito di dati con  {facce} facce!!')
        elif facce !=6 :
            print(f'stai giocando a d&d')
        else:
            print(f'un classico dado a facce {facce} ')

    def tira (self):
        from random import randint
        print(f'tiro il dado a {self.facce} facce..!!')
        self.risultato = randint(1, self.facce)
        print(f'il risultato è {self.risultato}')
                
    def leggi (self):
        if not self.risultato:
            print('non hai ancora tirato il dado..!!')
        else:
            print(f'il dado mostra {dado.risultato} punti.')
```

No error detected but there's no output when the code is run.

Comment: What's the expected output? How do you call this code? What data are you running it with?

Comment: Hi, the class is called game dice. I should have, fixed the number of faces, a random number that represents the points of the game dice. Thanks for cooperation